# Interview: Tell age or not?

Tags: interviewing, resume, czech-republic

How important is it to tell your age in the interview question 'Tell me about yourself'?

I am an 18 year-old with 3 years of professional experience, which might come across as weird to some employers. Is it a smart idea to tell my age when answering the question above? I did not put a birth date on my resume.

I am from The Netherlands, but I am applying for a job in the Czech Republic.

Answer (score 14):

Do not. It is a protected category. They are not legally allowed to ask you. It only creates difficulty for the interviewer from there, either in the psychological difficulty of separating your age from your evaluation, or in the fact that rejecting you now requires a compliance case that it is not age-discrimination.

Comment: Is it a protected category in the Czech Republic?

Comment: @DDT According to Wikipedia, it is in all EU countries (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageism#European_Union)

Comment: @JeroenMiddelbeers This is true, but for instance in Poland, according to article 22 of the Labour Code, employer may demand some information and among them there is a date of birth. I don't know law in the Czech Republic but it could be similar.

Comment: @DDT Well yes, date of birth may be necessary for all sorts of things once an employee has been taken on (calculating when a pension becomes payable, for example), or HR in the take-on process (to make sure the person is not too young to employ), but it should not be available to *interviewers*; it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

Age is not a factor in a job unless you are too old to perform a job or too young by law to perform a job.

Concentrate on your years of experience and your knowledge on the subject.

As long as your are of legal age to work that job per the areas laws then there is no reason to mention your age.

Comment: You should be more precise than "is not a factor." for instance, an employer may factor in when an employee will probably retire, or when a woman may be likely to go on maternity leave. if the job is physically demanding the employer may be concerned about back problems etc.

Comment: @djechlin, most of those examples are exactly things you are not allowed to filter for.

Comment: @HLGEM and they are of course prohibited because many employers love to consider them as a factor.

Answer (score 3):

There is never an advantage to revealing your age in an interview.  At best, it will be seen as adding "filler", at worst, it will trigger someone's biases.

Anything you can't use as a selling point for getting the job is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at this from different aspects.

Is it appropriate for the interviewer to ask for your age during interview? No it is not appropriate.

Should I reveal my age voluntarily ? **Up to you, there is nothing wrong in it.**

**I personally do reveal it** whenever the interviewer ask me to tell him more about myself, I give him a quick person background and my age is a part of it.

**Why do I do that?** I do it because, it gives the interviewer a level of confidence about me. When the interviewer sees my resume and background he always assumes I am 8 to 10 years older than my actual age. By revealing my real age I am telling him that I am someone who has held position beyond his birth certificate age.

**To summarize, If you think your profile is beyond your age, go ahead and tell them your age as it gives them a level of confidence about your character.**