# Mentioning my age when skill level is of someone 5 years older

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, skills

I am currently 22 yrs old and a Software developer, i have worked in many countries and have an extremely complete CV (Over 6 companies, 4 languages).

Usually they realize how young i am when i actually show up to work. but, i was wondering, since my skill level is more in line with someone that is 30, (in Canada most people are in university at my age) is it worth it to mention my age after my skill set?

I see it as either a "This guy is a prodigy" or "He must be lying about his skills".

Should i mention my age?

Comment: If the company is concerned about your age, you won't get past the interview, regardless of 'skill'. Your age will come out when you turn up to the first meeting.

Comment: Correct, but a lot of my interviews are online first and then in person, i rather be a candidate for as long as possible instead of killing my opportunity early on

Comment: My first reaction when reading your question is that there's a strong likelihood of [Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) at play here. Just let your skills speak for themselves - your age isn't relevant if your work-output shows through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interview: Tell age or not?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93067/interview-tell-age-or-not)

Comment: If you started working professionally at 18, that's 6+ companies in 4 years!  That sounds like a job-hopper - you didn't ask about this, but unless you're in consulting, you need to find a place where you can stay for a while.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I was very much thinking the same, It's essentially each job lasting less than a year, and mentioning that its been using 4 languages means you likely have about 1 year professional experience in each language, which very much (in my eyes) leaves you in the band of a "Junior" in that tech

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what impression you want to project?

Comment: *i rather be a candidate for as long as possible instead of killing my opportunity early on* You may know this already, but if you're implying that employers are rejecting you simply because they found out you're a certain age (or you have the appearance of having a certain age), that's illegal in Canada.

Comment: I went through this at age 27 (22 years ago), documenting 15 years of actual experience doing software dev.  The HR office didn't realize until I had been in the position for several months (required a masters degree or 10+ years relevant experience) and to make them happy I provided a very in-depth CV/resume that fully documented all of my experience.  Never heard another word, here I am at the same institution after moving through several positions, all increasing in responsibility and pay.  In short, if you have a verifiable CV/resume to prove you have the years of experience, don't worry!

Comment: Skill and experience aren't directly related to age. Saying that you have the skill of someone 5 years older than you makes no sense and isn't measurable in any significant way.

Comment: If I work at 1 company my entire career and speak only 1 language, is my CV incomplete? I'm not understanding how the number of companies and languages is relevant to "completeness".

Answer (score 11):

Why would anyone care what your age was at work?  They should be more concerned with your skill level relevant to the job.

If you're under the impression that you will be judged unfairly if you tell them your age, then don't.  If it's a concern, just don't talk about it.  If someone else brings it up, tell them (it shouldn't be a secret) and then if they give you grief about it, ask why it matters.

The average employee should not be surprised by a skilled coworker, regardless of age.  If you have the skills, they will speak for themselves. Especially when working in IT, it is expected that younger generations will have a greater baseline knowledge than their elders did at the same age. But this post seems more like self-gratification than an actual question so maybe I'm wasting my time.

Comment: "...this post seems more like self-gratification than an actual question so maybe I'm wasting my time." Indeed!

Comment: Judging from the post... OP shouldn't post hist age, there is a real question about maturity here and his age would definitely confirm that assumption.

Comment: "...this post seems more like self-gratification than an actual question so maybe I'm wasting my time." This is a very real problem. I started programming for money at 17. I likely didn't get a promotion at 23 because the job required more experience than "age - graduation age", even though I had it.

Comment: @JulieinAustin If you actually weren't given the promotion because of your age, that points to a larger issue with the company and not the industry as a whole. At the company I work for, there are many managers who are younger than their employees.  In general, if you have the skills for the job, you have proven you have those skills to your  management, and you have the interpersonal skills to work the position you will receive the promotion.  If you don't there's some other underlying factor.  I'm doubtful they didn't offer the promotion purely because of age, but it is possible I suppose

Answer (score 4):

No.    In the US in particular, it's illegal to ask the question.    It's irrelevant to the job.    You can either do the work, or not.

The same could be asked of the 60 year old man who wonders "Should I tell them my age?" Because, after all, the stereotype is that older people can't keep up in the tech world, right?

Prove you can do the work and no one will care.

Answer (score 2):

**I wouldn't advertise your age uninvited.** Whether on a resume, a company profile, or elsewhere, adding your age is either going to be taken as cavalier or a reason to doubt your ability.

**Let your experience and reputation speak for itself.** So long as you get the job done well and are respectful and collaborative with those around you, I don't think many folks will be concerned with your age.

If your colleagues ask you about your age, you should disclose it as you feel it's appropriate - even then, I would resist revealing a specific age.